# R boxcox not working

Tags: r, object, types, closures

```
data1 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Group_22.csv")

View(data1)

E_var <- regmatches(names(data1), regexpr("(E[0-9])+", names(data1)))  
G_var <- regmatches(names(data1), regexpr("(G[0-9]*)+", names(data1))) 

(E_vs_G  <- paste0(c(gsub(" ", "*", outer(E_var, G_var, paste))), collapse = "+"))
(G_eff_1 <- paste("I(", G_var, ")", collapse="+"))
(G_eff_2 <- paste("I(", apply( combn(G_var, 2), 2, paste, collapse="*"), ")", collapse="+"))
(G_eff_3 <- paste("I(", apply( combn(G_var, 3), 2, paste, collapse="*"), ")", collapse="+"))
(E_eff  <- paste0("I(", E_var,"^2", ")", collapse = "+"))

(formula <- paste( "I(log(Y)) ~" , paste(c(E_eff, G_eff_1, G_eff_2, G_eff_3, E_vs_G), collapse = "+")))

M <- lm(formula, data=data1)
summary(M)

anova(M)

install.packages('MASS')

library(MASS)

boxcox(M)

Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

the code runs properly except when it gets to boxcox(M) it gives me that error. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a particularly vague and non-helpful error, but if you understand [what a "closure" is](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) then it might provide insight on where to look. Unfortunately, here it is a little difficult to find it ...

### TL;DR

Rename your variable from `formula` to anything else that is not a function name. Your code works fine if you use `frm <- paste(...)`, for instance.

NB: this is a classic example of why you should **avoid naming variables the same as a function**. Often you'll see variables named just `data`. In this case, `formula` *is a function* that, due to package search paths, is not found in the order you would expect.

### Explanation

To find out why, first we need to debug the specific function being called. We can use `debug(boxcox)` and step our way into it, or we can do `debug(MASS:::boxcox.lm)` to make sure we debug the correct one. Regardless ...

```
boxcox(M)
# debugging in: boxcox.lm(M)
# debug: {
#     m <- length(lambda)
#     if (is.null(object$y) || is.null(object$qr)) 
#         object <- update(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
#     result <- NextMethod()
#     if (plotit) 
#         invisible(result)
#     else result
# }
```

Stepping through this, it fails with the call to `update`. Not very informative, we'll need to step within that. We can use `s` to step into the function. (By the way, it's using `MASS:::update.loglm`, not an export function.)

```
# Browse[2]> 
s
# debugging in: update(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
# debug: UseMethod("update")
# Browse[3]> 
s
# debugging in: update.default(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
# debug: {
#     if (is.null(call <- getCall(object))) 
#         stop("need an object with call component")
#     extras <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
#     if (!missing(formula.)) 
#         call$formula <- update.formula(formula(object), formula.)
#     if (length(extras)) {
#         existing <- !is.na(match(names(extras), names(call)))
#         for (a in names(extras)[existing]) call[[a]] <- extras[[a]]
#         if (any(!existing)) {
#             call <- c(as.list(call), extras[!existing])
#             call <- as.call(call)
#         }
#     }
#     if (evaluate) 
#         eval(call, parent.frame())
#     else call
# }
```

Stepping through this, it fails on the last command, `eval(call, parent.frame())`. Not very helpful still, but it's useful while troubleshooting to look at the variables R thinks it is using. For instance, earlier:

```
# Browse[2]> 
object
# Call:
# lm(formula = formula, data = data1)
# Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)      I(cyl^2)     I(disp^2)         I(hp)       I(drat)  I(hp * drat)           cyl  
#    3.274e+00    -2.006e-02     9.589e-06    -1.250e-02     2.388e-01     5.869e-04     4.034e-01  
#           hp          disp          drat        cyl:hp       hp:disp      cyl:drat     disp:drat  
#           NA    -9.728e-03            NA     2.122e-03    -2.418e-05    -1.155e-01     2.064e-03
```

Okay, that looks correct. Next, realize that the `eval` call is trying to recall the previous model with an update to it.

```
# Browse[4]> 
call
# lm(formula = formula, data = data1)
```

That looks similar to how we called it the first time. However, looking at the actual variables, `data1` looks correct but ...

```
# Browse[4]> 
formula
# function (x, ...) 
# UseMethod("formula")
# <bytecode: 0x000000001a5c20a0>
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

Oh. So the `formula` being referenced in the recent call to `lm` is not reaching back to the original calling environment, even with `eval(...,parent.frame())`.

If you instead use:

```
(frm <- paste( "I(log(Y)) ~" , paste(c(E_eff, G_eff_1, G_eff_2, G_eff_3, E_vs_G), collapse = "+")))
M <- lm(frm, data=data1)
```

then things work fine.